# How to make changes in class variables based on the value passed without using switch

Tags: java

Let's say I have following class:

```
@Getters
public class Metrics {
    private String length;
    private String width;
    private String height;
    private String volume;

    public void changeMetric(string newValue, string metricVariable) {
       /*
         based on metricVariable value (which can be "length", "width", "height" or "volume")
         change the corresponding private variable with the newValue.
       */
    }
}
```

`changeMetric` can be implemented using *switch case*, however it would take lot of code incase the number of private variables is large.

Is there any annotation, framework or other solution, which can directly change the corresponding private `metricVariable` without iterating to each one of them?

Comment: use a HashMap instead of individual data members.

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes it can be one of the solutions however we need to use different logic for fetching the values (instead of using Getters annotation).

Comment: If you must have named variables (instead of an addressable collection) for the attributes, then you're stuck with `switch` or `if-then-else`.  It's not really clear what you're after here.

Comment: @JimGarrison won't switch case or if-else requires multiple lines of code ? that is what i want to reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing that, because the `String metricVariable` you transfer is just an array of characters, nothing else. You should absolutely not use *switch-case*, as you explicitly have to connect each variable to the corresponding `String`.

A `Map<String, ?>` is for mapping any arbitrary String (*name*) to a corresponding *value*, but as your values are clearly defined, this is not a solution for this case.

You can make your *attributes* `public` if you want them to be changed from everywhere.

To have more control over what is happening with your *attributes*, you can use [getters and setters](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp).

Using a `String` to reference your *attributes* (variables) is **bad style**, but you can do it using [reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection):

```
public void changeMetric(String newValue, String metricVariable) {
    Metrics.class.getDeclaredField(metricVariable).set(this, newValue);
}
```

Note:

`String` is a `class` and thus has to start with an uppercase s.

Comment: "There is no direct way", I mentioned in problem: "Is there any annotation or framework or any other solution with help of which we can directly change the corresponding private metricVariable without iterating to each one of them.". If reflection works then that's what I wanted !